# undefined method `comment' for nil:NilClass (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby on Rails I'm trying to render a JSON file that will map each comment to a review. Each review has many comments but each comment belongs to a review.

Here is my controller to generate a JSON file:

```
 reviews: @ship.reviews.preload(:user_profile).map do |review|
        {
          id: review.id,
          body: review.body,
          rating: review.rating,
          user_profile: review.user_profile,
          comments: @review.comments.preload(:comment).map do |comment|
            {
              id: comment.id,
              body: comment.body,
              user_profile: comment.user_profile_id,
            }
          end
        }
```

Here is the comment model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_profile
  belongs_to :review
end
```

Here is the review.rb model:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_profile
  belongs_to :ship
  has_many :comments
  has_many :helpfuls
end
```

However my JSON file returns an error:

```
undefined method `comment' for nil:NilClass
```

on this line:

```
comments: @review.comment.preload(:comment).map do |comment|
```

Comment: Possibly the error is because `@review` is not referring to `review` in the line `reviews: @ship.reviews.preload(:user_profile).map do |review|`. Try removing the `@` to refer the variable in the scope of the `map`. The `@` is for instance variables of a class.

Comment: thanks.           'comments: review.comments.map do |comment|' worked

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.preload(:commment)` from `@review.comments.preload(:comment).map do |comment|`. You don't need it at all.

Comment: thanks. 'comments: review.comments.map do |comment|' work